# Mover Draggable para direita e esquerda e fazer recorte das dimensões

Tags: php, ajax, ui-draggable

tenho uma rede social com wowonder, fiz uma modificação na página de timeline, tirei a imagem de capa do topo no formato de banner, e coloquei na lateral, com a dimensão de 280x500, acontece que o Draggable não quer funcionar corretamente nessa nova dimensão.
1º. O Draggable não quer mover a imagem;
2º. O Draggable não faz o recorte da imagem na dimensão correta;

Gostaria de pode resolver essa questão. Preciso muito resolver esse problema!

Segue trecho do código Draggable:

```
scroll: false,
    axis: "y",
    cursor: "-webkit-grab",
    drag: function (event, ui) {
        y1 = $('.user-cover-reposition-container').height();
        y2 = $('.user-reposition-container').find('img').height();
        if (ui.position.top >= 0) {
            ui.position.top = 0;
        }else
            if (ui.position.top <= (y1-y2)) {
                ui.position.top = y1-y2;
            }
        },                                 
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            $('input.cover-position').val(ui.position.top);
        }
    });
```

Agora um trecho do HTML:

```
<div class="card hovercard" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
        <div class="cardheader user-cover">
            <?php if ($IsOwner === true) { ?>
                <form action="#" method="post" class="profile-cover-changer">
                    <div class="input-group when-notedit">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <span class="btn btn-upload-image btn-file">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-camera"><path d="M23 19a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H3a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V8a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h4l2-3h6l2 3h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2z"></path><circle cx="12" cy="13" r="4"></circle></svg>
                                <input type="file" name="cover" accept="image/*" onchange="Wo_UpdateProfileCover();">
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-btn when-notedit">
                            <span class="btn btn-upload-image btn-file" onclick="Wo_StartRepositioner();">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-crop"><path d="M6.13 1L6 16a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h15"></path><path d="M1 6.13L16 6a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v15"></path></svg>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group when-edit" style="display: none;">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <span class="btn btn-upload-image btn-file" onclick="Wo_SubmitRepositioner();">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-check"><polyline points="20 6 9 17 4 12"></polyline></svg>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group when-edit" style="display: none;">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <span class="btn btn-upload-image btn-file" onclick="Wo_StopRepositioner();">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-x"><line x1="18" y1="6" x2="6" y2="18"></line><line x1="6" y1="6" x2="18" y2="18"></line></svg>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $wo['user_profile']['user_id']; ?>">
                </form>
                <form class="cover-position-form hidden" method="post">
                    <input class="cover-position" name="pos" value="0" type="hidden">
                        <input class="image_type" name="image_type" value="0" type="hidden">
                            <input name="cover_image" id="cover-input-image" value="<?php echo $wo['user_profile']['cover_org'] ?>" type="hidden">
                                <input name="real_image" id="full-input-image" value="<?php echo Wo_GetMedia($wo['user_profile']['cover_full']); ?>" type="hidden">
                                    </form>
                                <?php } ?>
                                <div class="user-cover-uploading-container"></div>
                                <div class="user-cover-uploading-progress">
                                    <div class="pace-activity-parent"><div class="pace-activity"></div></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="user-cover-reposition-container">
                                    <div class="user-cover-reposition-w">
                                        <img id="cover-image" src="<?php echo $wo['user_profile']['cover'] ?>" alt="<?php echo $wo['user_profile']['name'] ?> Cover Image" onclick="Wo_OpenProfileCover('<?php echo $wo['user_profile']['cover_org'] ?>');" class="pointer" style="height:500px;"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="user-reposition-container">
                                        <img style="height:500px;" id="full-image" src="<?php echo Wo_GetMedia($wo['user_profile']['cover_full']) ?>" alt="User Image"/>
                                        <div class="user-reposition-dragable-container" align="center">
                                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-move"><polyline points="5 9 2 12 5 15"></polyline><polyline points="9 5 12 2 15 5"></polyline><polyline points="15 19 12 22 9 19"></polyline><polyline points="19 9 22 12 19 15"></polyline><line x1="2" y1="12" x2="22" y2="12"></line><line x1="12" y1="2" x2="12" y2="22"></line></svg>
                                            <?php echo $wo['lang']['drag_to_re']; ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="user-cover-uploading-container user-repositioning-icons-container1"></div>
                                        <div class="user-cover-uploading-progress user-repositioning-icons-container"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="problackback"></div>

                                <div class="pic-info-cont">
                                    <div class="user-avatar flip">
                                        <div class="user-avatar-uploading-container">
                                            <div class="user-avatar-uploading-progress">
                                                <div class="ball-pulse"><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <img id="updateImage-<?php echo $wo['user_profile']['user_id'] ?>" class="pointer" alt="<?php echo $wo['user_profile']['name'] ?> Profile Picture" src="<?php echo $wo['user_profile']['avatar'] ?>" onclick="Wo_OpenProfilePicture('<?php echo $wo['user_profile']['avatar_org'] ?>');"/>
                                        <?php if ($IsOwner === true) { ?>
                                            <form action="#" method="post" class="profile-avatar-changer">
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                                        <span class="btn btn-upload-image btn-file">
                                                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-camera"><path d="M23 19a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H3a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V8a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h4l2-3h6l2 3h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2z"></path><circle cx="12" cy="13" r="4"></circle></svg>
                                                            <input type="file" name="avatar" accept="image/x-png, image/jpeg" onchange="Wo_UpdateProfileAvatar();">
                                                        </span>
                                                        <?php if ($wo['user_profile']['avatar_org'] != $wo['userDefaultAvatar']) { ?>
                                                            <span class="btn btn-upload-image btn-file" onclick="OpenCropModal()">
                                                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-crop"><path d="M6.13 1L6 16a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h15"></path><path d="M1 6.13L16 6a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v15"></path></svg>
                                                            </span>
                                                        <?php } ?>
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
                                                <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user-id" value="<?php echo $wo['user_profile']['user_id']; ?>">
                                            </form>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="info">
                                        <div class="title">
                                            <a href="<?php echo Wo_SeoLink('index.php?link1=timeline&u=' . $wo['user_profile']['username'] . ''); ?>" data-ajax="?link1=timeline&u=<?php echo $wo['user_profile']['username']; ?>">
                                                <?php echo $wo['user_profile']['name']; ?>
                                            </a>
                                            <?php if ($wo['user_profile']['verified'] == 1) { ?>
                                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="verified-color feather feather-check-circle" title="<?php echo $wo['lang']['verified_user']; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip"><path d="M23,12L20.56,9.22L20.9,5.54L17.29,4.72L15.4,1.54L12,3L8.6,1.54L6.71,4.72L3.1,5.53L3.44,9.21L1,12L3.44,14.78L3.1,18.47L6.71,19.29L8.6,22.47L12,21L15.4,22.46L17.29,19.28L20.9,18.46L20.56,14.78L23,12M10,17L6,13L7.41,11.59L10,14.17L16.59,7.58L18,9L10,17Z"></path></svg>
                                            <?php } ?>

                                            <?php
                                            if (Wo_IsUserPro($wo['user_profile']['is_pro']) === true) {
                                                $user_pro_type = Wo_GetUserProType($wo['user_profile']['pro_type']);
                                                ?>
                                                <span class="badge-pro" style="background-color:<?php echo $user_pro_type['color_name']; ?>">
                                                    <a class="badge-link" href="<?php echo Wo_SeoLink('index.php?link1=go-pro'); ?>" title="<?php echo $user_pro_type['type_name']; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip">PRO</a>
                                                </span>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="options-buttons">
                                            <span class="user-follow-button btn-glossy">
                                                <?php echo Wo_GetFollowButton($wo['user_profile']['user_id']); ?>
                                            </span>
                                            <span class="profile-message-btn btn-glossy">
                                                <?php echo Wo_GetMessageButton($wo['user_profile']['user_id']); ?>
                                            </span>
                                            <?php if ($IsOwnerUser === true) { ?>
                                                <span class="btn-glossy">
                                                    <a class="btn btn-default" href="<?php echo Wo_SeoLink('index.php?link1=setting&user=' . $wo['user_profile']['username'] . '&page=general-setting') ?>" data-ajax="?link1=setting&user=<?php echo $wo['user_profile']['username'] . '&page=general-setting'; ?>">
                                                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-edit-2"><polygon points="16 3 21 8 8 21 3 21 3 16 16 3"></polygon></svg>
                                                        <?php echo $wo['lang']['edit']; ?>
                                                    </a>
                                                </span>
                                            <?php } else { ?>
                                                <?php if ($wo['loggedin'] == true) { ?>
                                                    <div class="dropup btn-glossy">
                                                        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="user-dropdownMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                                                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-more-vertical"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="1"></circle><circle cx="12" cy="5" r="1"></circle><circle cx="12" cy="19" r="1"></circle></svg>
                                                        </button>
                                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="user-dropdownMenu">
                                                            <?php if ($IsOwnerUser === false && $wo['loggedin'] == true) { ?>
                                                                <li>
                                                                    <span class="menu-item">
                                                                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-slash"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle><line x1="4.93" y1="4.93" x2="19.07" y2="19.07"></line></svg>
                                                                        <a href="<?php echo $wo['marker'] . 'block_user=block' ?>"><?php echo $wo['lang']['block_user']; ?></a>
                                                                    </span>
                                                                </li>
                                                            <?php } ?>
                                                            <?php if ($IsOwnerUser === false && $wo['loggedin'] == true && !Wo_IsFamilyMemberExists($wo['user']['id'], $wo['user_profile']['id'], false)) { ?>
                                                                <li id="open_add_to_family_modal">
                                                                    <span class="menu-item">
                                                                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-user-plus" style="margin: -4px 11px auto 2px;"><path d="M16 21v-2a4 4 0 0 0-4-4H5a4 4 0 0 0-4 4v2"></path><circle cx="8.5" cy="7" r="4"></circle><line x1="20" y1="8" x2="20" y2="14"></line><line x1="23" y1="11" x2="17" y2="11"></line></svg>
                                                                        <span onclick="$('#add_to_family').modal('show');"><span class="pointer"><?php echo $wo['lang']['add_to_family']; ?></span></span>
                                                                    </span>
                                                                </li>
                                                            <?php } ?>
                                                            <?php if ($wo['loggedin'] == true && $IsOwner) { ?>
                                                                <li id="open_add_to_family_modal">
                                                                    <span class="menu-item">
                                                                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-edit-3"><polygon points="14 2 18 6 7 17 3 17 3 13 14 2"></polygon><line x1="3" y1="22" x2="21" y2="22"></line></svg>
                                                                        <a href="<?php echo Wo_SeoLink('index.php?link1=setting&user=' . $wo['user_profile']['username'] . '&page=general-setting') ?>"><?php echo $wo['lang']['edit']; ?></a>
                                                                    </span>
                                                                </li>
                                                            <?php } ?>
                                                            <?php if ($wo['loggedin'] && !Wo_IsAdmin() && $wo['user']['id'] != $wo['user_profile']['id'] && !Wo_IsAdmin($wo['user_profile']['id'])): ?>
                                                                <?php if (!Wo_IsReportExists($wo['user_profile']['id'], 'user')): ?>
                                                                    <li id="report_status" onclick="$('#report_profile').modal('show');">
                                                                        <span class="menu-item">
                                                                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-alert-triangle"><path d="M10.29 3.86L1.82 18a2 2 0 0 0 1.71 3h16.94a2 2 0 0 0 1.71-3L13.71 3.86a2 2 0 0 0-3.42 0z"></path><line x1="12" y1="9" x2="12" y2="13"></line><line x1="12" y1="17" x2="12" y2="17"></line></svg>
                                                                            <span><?php echo $wo['lang']['report_user']; ?></span>
                                                                        </span>
                                                                    </li>
                                                                <?php else: ?>
                                                                    <li id="report_status" onclick="Wo_ReportProfile(<?php echo $wo['user_profile']['id']; ?>, false);">
                                                                        <span class="menu-item">
                                                                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-alert-triangle"><path d="M10.29 3.86L1.82 18a2 2 0 0 0 1.71 3h16.94a2 2 0 0 0 1.71-3L13.71 3.86a2 2 0 0 0-3.42 0z"></path><line x1="12" y1="9" x2="12" y2="13"></line><line x1="12" y1="17" x2="12" y2="17"></line></svg>
                                                                            <span><?php echo $wo['lang']['unreport']; ?></span>
                                                                        </span>
                                                                    </li>
                                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </div>
                                                <?php } ?>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: Tens a imagem como uma <img> ou background?

Comment: justamente a imagem d background, que é a capa, redelive.com crie uma conta rapida

Comment: No código assim não tens nenhuma img em bacckground.

Comment: <img id="cover-image" src="<?php echo $wo['user_profile']['cover'] ?>" alt="<?php echo $wo['user_profile']['name'] ?> Cover Image" onclick="Wo_OpenProfileCover('<?php echo $wo['user_profile']['cover_org'] ?>');" class="pointer" style="height:500px;"/>

Comment: <img style="height:500px;" id="full-image" src="<?php echo Wo_GetMedia($wo['user_profile']['cover_full']) ?>" alt="User Image"/>

Comment: Isso não são background img é um elemento <img>... e exprimentar meter "width: 280px;"